# How to replicate a postgresql database from local to web server

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication, postgresql-11

I am new in the form and also new in postgresql.

Normally I use MySQL for my project but I’ve decided to start migrating towards postgresql for some valid reasons which I found in this database.
Expanding on the problem:
I need to analyze data via some mathematical formulas but in order to do this I need to get the data from the software via the API.

The software, the API and Postgresql v. 11.4 which I installed on a desktop are running on windows. So far I’ve managed to take the data via the API and import it into Postgreql.

My problem is how to transfer this data from
the local Postgresql (on the PC ) to a web Postgresql (installed in a Web server ) which is running Linux.

For example if I take the data every five minutes from software via API and put it in local db postgresql, how can I transfer this data (automatically if possible) to the db in the web server running Linux? I rejected a data dump because importing the whole db every time is not viable.
What I would like is to import only the five-minute data which gradually adds to the previous data.
I also rejected the idea of making a master - slave architecture
because not knowing the total amount of data, on the web server I have almost 2 Tb of hard disk while on the local pc I have only one hard disk that serves only to take the data and then to send it to the web server for the analysis.

Could someone please help by giving some good advice regarding how to achieve this objective?
Thanks to all for any answers.

Comment: Can you just perform the same steps on your remote server that you take on your local (query the api and send to both databases?)

Comment: Why don't you keep everything on the WebServer?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestions. I'll do as you say, I'll perform the same steps on my remote server. Maybe is the way more easy.